# Problem about using subfigure with subcaption in one column of a double-column template

Tags: two-column, subcaption, subfig

I have the following code for my figures,

```
\usepackage{subfigure, subcaption, graphicx}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{\columnwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Caption for Subfigure 1}
    \label{fig:subfig1}
  \end{subfigure}
  
  \vspace{\baselineskip} % Add vertical space between subfigures
  
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{\columnwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Caption for Subfigure 2}
    \label{fig:subfig2}
  \end{subfigure}
  
  \caption{Overall Caption for the Two Subfigures}
  \label{fig:overall}
\end{figure}
```

And it generates:

[image]

I want to have captions like that (source [How to format multiple figures in one column in two-columns article?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/484080/how-to-format-multiple-figures-in-one-column-in-two-columns-article)):

[image]

When I use the same code provided for the previous figure, the result that I take is:

[image]

I do not know what is wrong with my latex code. How can I show one figure with two subfigures (with captions) in one column? I appreciate your help.

The template that I use is "IEEE for journals template with bibtex example files included" in overleaf.

Comment: PLase, extend your code fragment to complete small document: MWE (Minimal Working Example.) Help us to help you.

Comment: You should *under no circumstance* load both `subfigure` and `subcaption`.

Comment: You're totally right @Mico. I solved the issue by removing subfigure from usepackages

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, a general comment: You should *under no circumstance* load both the `subfigure` and the `subcaption` package. Indeed, as the `subfigure` package is deprecated, you shouldn't load it at all.

Here's a solution that's very similar to the one in [@Zarko's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/686450/5001). It makes use of the `article` document class in two-column mode along with the `graphicx` and `subcaption` packages.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article} % or some other suitable document class.
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional (Times Roman fonts)
\usepackage{graphicx} % for '\includegraphics' macro

\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{skip=0.2\baselineskip}
\captionsetup[figure]{skip=0.5\baselineskip}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-7] % a few lines of filler text

\begin{figure}[ht]
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}

  \begin{subfigure}{0.49\columnwidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \caption{Image A} \label{fig:wow:1}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill % maximize the horizontal separation
  \begin{subfigure}{0.49\columnwidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image-b}
    \caption{Image B} \label{fig:wow:2}
  \end{subfigure}

  \medskip % increase the separation between rows
  
  \begin{subfigure}{0.49\columnwidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image-c}
    \caption{Image C} \label{fig:wow:3}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill % maximize the horizontal separation
  \begin{subfigure}{0.49\columnwidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image}
    \caption{Image D} \label{fig:wow:4}
  \end{subfigure}

\caption{Wow! Look at all these letters!}
\label{fig:wow}

\end{figure}

\lipsum[2-7] % six paragraphs of filler text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The problem was related to subfigure. When I removed subfigure usepackage and only left subcaption, it worked.

Answer (score 3):

As Starting point_

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.48\linewidth}
        \includegraphics{example-image-a}
        \caption{Image A}
        \label{fig:subfig1}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.48\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image-b}
    \caption{Image B}
    \label{fig:sunfgi2}
\end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}{0.48\linewidth}
        \includegraphics{example-image-c}
        \caption{Image C}
        \label{fig:sunfgi3}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.48\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image}
    \caption{Image D}
    \label{fig:subfgi4}
\end{subfigure}
    \caption{Image}
    \label{fig: overall}
\end{figure}
```

which should generate something close to this:

[image]

For more details you need to provide MWE as (I ask you in comment).

Comment: +1. The subfigures don't appear to span the full column width, though. Is this intentional?

Comment: @Mico, actually not. I just copy some of my old answers with two parallel subfigures. However, it will be better to use your approach  (wider figures, use `\hfill` ...) as you do in your answer  (+1)

Comment: Thank you for your response @Zarko